# Why is this question getting so many views?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question has over 6,000 views at the time of writing,

[https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/956/was-einstein-really-a-poor-student](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/956/4)

And the author has got the Popular and Notable question badges so it not a display bug.

What gives?

Comment: When I logged in today I thought it was an error.  At 7k now...gold badge coming up?  Booyah!  But seriously, very surprised.  Not that this site is all about the rep and badges, but I feel a TINY bit guilty because it was spurred on by the good meta question and responses here.  I gave my props in a comment, weak as that is.  Not what I thought would happen, but hopefully it draws new blood to the site!  I hope we have a dozen more questions like it soon, even if we can't explain why.

Comment: Makes my attempts at sharing on facebook seem rather pathetic.  :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found [this website that linked to the article](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2339879), although I don't know it and don't know if it can drive that amount of traffic alone.

Comment: That's Hacker News. Believe me, it can. Stack Exchange requires that [the sidesick to its CEO reads it](http://stackexchange.com/about/hiring). That should give you an idea of how influential it is amongst programmers.

Answer (score 0):

Also because it is marvellous click bait. Or call it human interest. This is what popular magazines and tabloids thrive on. Since it's humans visiting this site, this will add to the click count.